# Where are the cshtml files for the built in SPEAK UI layouts and renderings

Tags: presentation, speak

I'm working with SPEAK UI (Sitecore 9.2) and am attempting to understand more about how the built-in components are structured. Looking at the layout `Speak-FlexLayout` I see that the Path specified is `/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Layouts/Speak-FlexLayout.cshtml`

[image: Screenshot of Sitecore Rocks with Speak-FlexLayout selected]

However, when I look at the file system I cannot find the file specified:
[image]

I can find `sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts` but it doesn't have a `Layouts` folder beneath it.
Is there some file path mapping going on here?

Comment: Which version of Sitecore you are using?

Comment: @SumitBhatia 9.2 - sorry to miss that. Updated the question to mention version now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those views are not physically available in the webroot, they use view `precompilation` for performance reasons. For example the view you are mentioning is precompiled in the `Sitecore.Speak.Web` assembly. If you decompile this you will find some code like below which has the precompiled code for the view:

```
[GeneratedCode("RazorGenerator", "2.0.0.0")]
[PageVirtualPath("~/sitecore/shell/client/Speak/Layouts/Layouts/Speak-FlexLayout.cshtml")]
public class _sitecore_shell_client_Speak_Layouts_Layouts_Speak_FlexLayout_cshtml : WebViewPage<RenderingModel>
{
    public override void Execute()
    {
        //all precompiled code is here      
    }
}
```